# Elimination Method - 4 variables?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

$x+2y - 11z = 0$
$-5y-15z=0$
$3y+9z=0$
$x+y-14z = 0$

I got $y=-3z$ and $x=17z$ , but I can't go further. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Perfect solution, $z$ is a Free Variable and you have infinite solutions.

Comment: He said it perfect. $z$ is going to be any number you want, infinitely many choices. Once you pick a $z$ then you plug it into the two equations that you found for $x$ and $y$ and you'll have one specific solution.